# Internet Explorer (8+) shows blank page when opening new window

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm having some major problems with IE on my local machine.

When going to any website that uses either Window.Open or target="_blank", the new window/tab is opened, but then it just shows a white page with a busy cursor.

If I right click on a link and select "Open in New Tab/Window" or if I manually copy/paste the URL into a new window/tab it works fine.

Any idea's what the cause of this could be?

FYI, as much as I could, I have uninstalled Internet Explorer by removing all updates and then uninstalling it via the Add/Remote (advanced) and then reinstalled it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Reset Internet Explorer Setting  under "Internet Options" . Its fixed .

Answer (score 0):

Try to reregister your Java. Run your cmd.exe with Admin permissions and then type:

```
regsvr32 jscript.dll
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Type this instead:

```
regsvr32 urlmon.dll
```

<strike>If that doesn't help read this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281679</strike> - didn't see that it's very old...

Comment: Thanks Avall, unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Cannot open link in new tab ie10 - just installed internet explorer 10

This is an issue on IE 10 as well. There were lots of things on the internet but none of them worked for me. So i tried turning tabs off (under "internet options"), restarted IE and then turned tabs back on. Was fixed.

Comment: You could add this as comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with the following FixIt tool. It's the first time ever a FixIt actually solved something, I tried those countless times.

[A new window or tab does not open when you click a link in Internet Explorer 8 - FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2539060)